# Is there meta-cognition in machine learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, ai

I have very little knowledge about machine learning, but I'm wondering if some neural networks have in-built abilities to gauge their own ability to learn and their improvement, taking this as a training set as well, and thus learning to learn as they're learning the assigned task? Perhaps there are other networks given this training task, supervising and training the networks that are learning the assigned task?

I guess the "meta-cognitive" abilities could be improved if the neural network would train until mastery, and then have their data wiped clean, except for the meta-cognitive data, thus allowing it to continue training it, without the bottleneck of mastery over the assigned task.

So, my questions are this:

1. Are such meta-cognitive processes built into some neural networks?
2. If so, does it work well?
3. If so, is it more translatable than the abilities learned from the  training for the assigned task (the implication being that this might be the road to AGIs)?

Comment: This kind of question might also be asked on https://ai.stackexchange.com/, in case there's no good answer. In my opinion, this hypothesis relies on the common confusion between artificial neural networks and the human brain: the name emphasizes the analogy, but the two are very different in their structure and behaviour. For example afaik there's no plasticity in an artificial NN, a requirement for this hypothesis to work. But I'm not an expert at all on these topics.

Comment: @Erwan Surely some plasticity could be programmed in though? If an NN takes the correspondence between its decisions and its own improvement as training data and uses this to increase improvement, getting rewards for its improvement of its improvement?

Comment: I think what what you're describing exists, it's more or less the regular feedback mechanism over epochs when a NN is trained. However imho 'plasticity' would also require the possibility to rearrange the NN itself, i.e. its architecture, possibly also creating new connections from scratch, maybe even increasing in size. This could be much more tricky to do within a realistic computing duration. And let's not forget that the a NN is based on optimizing a mathematical function with various formal constraints, it's not so easy to design models which can actually solve something.

Comment: This is just my moderately well informed opinion though. An article which could be distantly related: https://www.noemamag.com/ai-and-the-limits-of-language/